# exact match with IN Operator in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

How to find exact match of multiple text values with IN operation? e.g.,

```
SELECT * WHERE name in ('george','michael') AND testID in (1,2)
```

When I try to run below query, it returns extra data for matching values e.g., "**the george**", not for the exact values only as "**george**"

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "query_string":{  
                  "fields":[  
                     "name"
                  ],
                  "query":"george or michael"
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "testID":[1,2]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post your mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your field `name` is of type `text`.

When datatype if of `text`, Elasticsearch breaks the values(for e.g `The George` or `George Washington` into tokens `[the, george]` or `[george, washington]` and saves these tokens in inverted index. Hence when you search on this field using the query you have, it would also return these documents i.e.what you say as not exact match.

For exact match I suggest you make use of `keyword` type using `lowercase` normalizer as mentioned in below mapping:

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "normalizer":{  
            "my_custom_normalizer":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "name":{  
               "type":"keyword",
               "normalizer":"my_custom_normalizer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

By doing so your values would be saved as is for e.g. based on above mapping, it would convert `The George` or `George Washington` into `the george` or `george washtingon` and then store them as is in the inverted index.

You can probably have the query you've mentioned then working as expected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Kamal, adding a normalizer would have any performance impact on the whole index while doing search or updating documents in an index?

Comment: It would only affect indexing process afaik which I think is acceptable. Keep in mind that if you intend to also have `partial matching`, you may need to implement `multi-field` for your field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html